# Form before submit when using onsubmit function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form

```html
<form id="form" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <input type="submit" value="next">
</form>
```

and this validation

```js
if ($("#name").val() == "") {
  return false;
}
return true;
```

what I am trying to do, is to disable the submit button, I tried to use submit function for the form but its not triggered, the problem is I don't have access to html or js files, only one custom.js file I can add or override other functions.

anyone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: You can override submit behavior using  jquery on submit event: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: @Artur I did that but its not working at all

Answer (score 0):

so if you have `$("#name")` probably you have the jquery library.

in this case you can try remove `onsubmit` html property directly and use this event from jquery. `$("#form").submit(...)` and there you can use your validation function with return boolean value

Comment: unfortunately as I mentioned, theres no access to the html files or javascript files, only custom javascript file

Comment: hm, really strange, in jsbin even your solution works fine - http://jsbin.com/zupojevama/edit?html,js,console,output 

maybe there is an issue with jquery library version or naming of the function

Answer (score 0):

You can override the **validate** function (but it is a bit dirty):

```js
function validate() {
  console.log('default validator');
  
  return false;
}

var defaultValidator = validate;

window.validate = function () {
  defaultValidator();
  console.log('custom validator');
  
  return false;
};
```

```html
<form id="form" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <input type="submit" value="next">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your validate function.

$('#form>submit').prop('disabled', true);